# Is it possible to transcode a video file with an ifs extension?

Tags: video, convert, transcode, avi

I have recovered video files recorded from a camera DVR which has an embedded Linux system and compresses in H264, the files are .ifs and I need to be able to make these files viewable on any computer but I can only view them on my Ubuntu machine using the media player with extra codecs.

Does anyone know what software I could use to transcode these .ifs files to edit and make them viewable on a windows machine?

Comment: Hmmmm question: are .IFS files not indexes? .VOB files are the actual videos? So why would these need to be transcoded?

Comment: That could very well be the case. I haven't worked with Linux systems much so im not to familiar with the ifs extension. If they are indexes how can I get the VOB?

Comment: If it is compressed in H264 then you can easily transcode it but remuxing can be more useful in this case, unless you need a different codec for a specific purpose. It will be useful if you provide a link with a downloadable  small .ifs video file in order to run some testing thus providing a good workaround.